# Swift 3 conversion typealiased closure conversion issue

Tags: swift, swift3

The actual Xcode error i get is:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(AnyObject?, _) -> ()' to expected argument type 'FOSSAPIResponseHandler?'
```

The typealias I defined as `FOSSAPIResponseHandler` is:

```
public typealias FOSSAPIResponseHandler = ((_ responseObject: Any?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void)
```

The method where i use that is:

```
public func getAccount(responseHandler: FOSSAPIResponseHandler?) {
    ...
}
```

And the error appears when i use the call:

```
self.networkingClient.getAccount { (responseObject, error) in

}
```

The error in xcode appears at the line `.getAccount {` to `in`.

Any help would be appreciated as this is literally the last error im seeing in Xcode during this tumultuous time of converting to Swift 3.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this – could you please create a [mcve]? Make sure you've tried cleaning your build folder.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the answer but I notice that the typealias uses Any? and it appears that the compiler thinks responseObject being passed in is an AnyObject rather than an Any. What's the declaration of responseObject (the one in the function call that's being flagged by the compiler)?

Comment: @Mikey responseObject is declared in the closure usage. The typealias declares the type. But using it, it seems it is inferring the type as an AnyObject.

Comment: @RohanPanchal, right. The compiler sees responseObject as an AnyObject. Prior to using it responseObject is declared. Is it `var responseObject:Any?`
No, wait. I reading that wrong. I realize now it's an anonymous function and the responseObject is being declared right there.

Comment: @Hamish I tried cleaning build folder. Done t multiple times.

Comment: @RohanPanchal Then please post a [mcve] of the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the following code in a clean playground :

```
typealias FOSSAPIResponseHandler = ((_ responseObject: Any?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void)

class NetworkingClient: NSObject {
    func getAccount(responseHandler: FOSSAPIResponseHandler?) {
        guard responseHandler != nil else { return }

        responseHandler!("Cool", nil)
    }
}

let networkingClient = NetworkingClient()

networkingClient.getAccount { (responseObject, error) in
    print (responseObject!)
}
```

It works perfectly (printing `Cool` in the console). So it should be something else in your code, something we're not seeing in the few lines of code you've shared. 
My first guess would be that you store the response handler somewhere in your `NetworkingClient` class, something similar with this :

```
var responseHandler: FOSSAPIResponseHandler?
```

Could you please verify that this var is using the same `FOSSAPIResponseHandler` typelias and not something else ?

PS. In either case, please add to my playground more and more of your code until you get the error and share it with us please.

Comment: So I attempted the same thing in XCode 8.2.1 with a playground and you are right.

I went back to the `FOSSAPIResponseHandler` and changed it from Any? to AnyObject? instead and it worked.

I think that it has some issue to do with the type inference.

Probably how i was using the responseObject was being used in the closure and it was causing conflicts.